# Error while installing pyodbc 4.0.39 with Python 3.12 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyodbc

Using Python `3.12.0` while attempting to install `pyodbc-4.0.39` on Windows 10 I get these error messages at the end of the installation (Win 10 22H2):

```
Failed to build pyodbc
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

I tried installation from an empty local folder, still get the same error.

Comment: Try downgrading to a lower version of python such as `3.11`

Comment: See this [discussion](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1113#discussioncomment-6832055)

Comment: Thank you, in 3.11 works OK. But, why shouldn't it be possible in the new version, it didn't concern ODBC.

Comment: @JiříBasler pyodbc 4.0.39 didn't have wheels for Python 3.12. pyodbc was just released and includes them.

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc 5.0.0 has just been released. It has wheels for Python 3.12.

Comment: Installed but failed to run:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/val/dev/ApiLogicServer/ApiLogicServer-dev/build_and_test/ApiLogicServer/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'